# XSLT 2.0 and JDeveloper 11g

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I'm doing transformation in Java and below is my XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<!-- Root template -->
<xsl:template match="/">
<Country>
<xsl:for-each-group select="/Country" group-by="City">
<City><xsl:value-of select="City"/></City>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</Country>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I got the below error

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group'
                at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:716)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:313)

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.5 and the Java JDK that comes with it.

Does JDeveloper 11g support XSLT 2.0? If not how can we add XSLT 2.0 support into it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With Java you can use Saxon 9, available in an open source version from http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/, to use XSLT 2.0.